# Partial derivative of an iterated function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, iterated-function-system

I'm trying to find the form of the partial derivative for the following function:

$F(F(x_{1},x_{2}),x_{2})$

I tried using the rules of composition:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{2}}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial F}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}$

And this was confusing so I changed the name of the external function to G:

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_{2}}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial F}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}$

And here I cannot find a way out. Because the result is $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_{2}}$ equal to itself plus another component. 
Can someone help me to understand my mistake please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what happens when one reuses a letter in writing the chain rule.

Let's write $G(x_1,x_2) = F(F(x_1,x_2),x_2)$. Then
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(F(x_1,x_2),x_2)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2).$$

Comment: Thank you but I have to ask: when you write $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{1}}(F,x_{2})$ do you actually mean $ x_1=F$? or I need to use a different name for the variable of differentiation in $F(F(x_1,x_2),x_2)$?

Comment: You do not differentiate with respect to a function; you differentiate with respect to a variable. $F$ is a function of two variables, and you differentiate it with respect to its two variables before anything else starts. You then evaluate at the point I indicated.